# IntelliTest Vs. Unit Test in Visual studio

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, intellitest

Those two features seem similar. I wonder when should I favor one over another?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IntelliTest can augment an existing unit testing practice you may be following already. Please see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/09/30/intellitest-for-net-test-more-with-less-effort/ for some thoughts. You do not have to choose one over the other. They are complementary.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. See this video, 3 min in :https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Intellitest